# Next.js dynamic routes don't work properly when deployed

Tags: reactjs, next.js, aws-amplify

I've built a website using Next.js where I have this folder structure:

```
pages
|- [path]
|  |- index.js
|   
|- [for-students]
|  |- [path]
|  |  |- index.js
|
| index.js
| events.js
```

Everything works great locally in development. The dynamic routes use the `getServerSideProps()` function to check if the requested route exists at the CMS: if they do, the page is rendered, if they don't, a 404 error is shown.

My problem starts when the website is deployed to AWS Amplify and I try to access a dynamic route like mysite.com/exemple or mysite.com/for-students/internship. If I navigate troughth the routes using the links in the page (e.g., navigation menu links) the dynamic pages loads correctly, but if I try to access those pages by typing the url it gives me a 500 error.
The error also is occur when I access the pages troughth the links and reload them.

I appreciate any help!

Edit:
As @Konrad Linkowski suggested, I checked the server logs, but they are very confusing... I don't even know what to look for.
[image]

Comment: Error 500 usually includes message explaining what went wrong in the server logs

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Hi! I added a screenshot of part of the logs to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem has nothing to do with routing.
What happened was that for all of my dynamic route pages I was calling a component and passing some content to it. Before calling this component, I checked if the content was valid, like so:

```
<div className="container">
{
 content &&
 <CustomContent content={ content }/>
}
</div>
```

Once I checked the validity of the content before passing it to the component, I didn't see the need to check it again inside the CustomContent component, so it was like so:

```
export default function CustomContent({ content }) {

   return (
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={
         { 
            __html: content.description ? content.description : "",
         }
      }/>
   )
}
```

For some reason that I don't know of, the content was "bypassing" the validity verification (content &&) and causing an error inside CustomComponent, because then it was trying to access the properties of an (probably) undefined object (e.g. content.description).

So I added another validity check inside the CustomContent component, and the error stoped.

```
export default function CustomContent({ content }) {

   return (
     <>
     {
        content ? 
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={
             { 
                __html: content.description ? content.description : "",
             }
          }/>
        : 
        <></>
     }
     </>
   )
}
```

I also don't get why the error was occurring only on the server and only when the page was reloaded or accessed troughth the url.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are developing their apps from Next.js V13, you would need to use generateStaticParams(). For more:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-static-params