# Dynamic route from Next.js does not work with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, next.js

I just deployed my web app built in Next.js onto AWS and weird thing happens:

All normal routes (e.g. xxx.com/pagename) work perfectly and the pages are accessible as normal.

All dynamic routes (e.g. xxx.com/pagename/:itemId) are not working and throw 502 errors.

I am sure that those pages do exist since I can access them without a problem when I run `next start` locally.

The app is accessed via Route 53 => CloudFront => ELB => EC2.

Has anyone encountered a similar case like this? How should I solve this issue?

PS. [Next.js dynamic routes don't work properly when deployed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74103571/next-js-dynamic-routes-dont-work-properly-when-deployed) I have read this and the content checker inside the page has already been applied. Also, the server didn't receive anything when the page throws the error. I believe it is a frontend or configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/15981

I found this issue and tried to remove the function `getServerSideProps` from my app. And now it works without an issue.

Luckily I have nothing that must be loaded in server-side rendering in my current project. Still wondering why it does not work on AWS.

Would leave this question open to see if there's any better solution for this.